# unable to play video on videos

Tags: video-player

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 but is unable to play videos which are playing perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04.But still manages to play on mpv media player.It get distorted while opening in videos.

Comment: have you installed all required codecs?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest You to switch to **VLC** media player. Codec problem should be gone as well, in case You have it.

Give it a try.

https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

Good luck, Merry Christmas,
Cheers, Paweł.